# Where could I get away with free camping on Corfu?

Tags: camping, legal, greece, islands

I've heard that Greece now has a law prohibiting free camping. But I've also heard that it's only enforced in touristy beach areas to protect the local accommodation businesses.

So which places in Corfu would free camping be OK? Are there some undeveloped beaches or would it be best not to be near a beach at all?

I'd prefer answers from people who have actually done free camping in Corfu or met people who were doing it.

Comment: I haven't done this personally, but when I was there I was staying at the pink palace. I met a guy who was camping out in some caves north of the hostel.

Comment: I'm now on mainland Greece and I've noticed people camping in vans at beaches even though they have no camping signs. I guess nobody minds if it's just for a night and it's out of season. The campground I passed didn't seem to be open anyway so I also camped at a lake beach just in my sleeping bag and had no problem. Maybe Corfu not very different.

Comment: A lot of laws (and taxes) are not kept to in Greece by the locals, however they will not tell you the ones  you have to keep to!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this website](http://www.holidaycorfu.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=88):

> Wild camping, or use of camping accommodation outside the authorized
>   campsites is strictly forbidden, with serious penalties (By Law
>   2160/93, article 4 and By Law 2741/99 article 21).

But I wouldn't take it too seriously since it is a site that lists all official camping sites. So they're clearly interested that no one does wild camping.

According to another [tourist information website](http://www.griechenland-insel.de/Hauptseiten/unterkuenfte.htm) (this time only in German), free camping is not allowed but especially on Greek islands is widely accepted. You should just not camp inside villages.

> Wild-Campen ist eigentlich verboten, wird aber häufig auf kleineren
>   Inseln toleriert. Wenn man es auf einen Versuch ankommen lässt, hat
>   man außerhalb von Ortschaften meist mehr Glück.

As an additional hint, I read in my message boards that one night shouldn't be a problem, but you should not stay more than one night in the same place. And if there is an official campsite just next to your free camping place, you will probably get more problems than in more remote areas.